# C++ Pure virtual derived function

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I'm learning about object oriented C++ and had a question about virtual/pure virtual and multi-level inheritance.

Lets say I have simple code like this:

```
class Shape
{
    virtual int getWidth() = 0;
};
class Rectangle: public Shape
{
private:
    int length, width;
public:
    Rectangle(_length, _width) { length = _length; width = _width }
    int getWidth() { return width }
};
class Square: public Rectangle
{
private:
    int length;
public:
    Square(int _length):Rectangle(_length, _length) { length = _length };
    int getWidth() { return length+1 }; //arbitarily add 1 to distinguish
};

int main()
{
    Rectangle* r = new Square(5);
    std::cout << r->getWidth << std::endl;  //prints 6 instead of 5?  It's as if rectangles getWidth is virtual
}
```

My understanding is that polymorphism will use the function of the "Base" class unless getWidth is specified as virtual.  By this I mean that the final call of r->getArea should be using the Rectangle's getArea instead of Square's getArea.

In this case, I notice if I remove the pure virtual declaration in Shape, we get the behavior I just described.  Does having a pure virtual function in a base class automatically make all definitions of that function virtual?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`virtual` is inherited. If you make a parent function `virtual` then it will keep on being `virtual` in all child-classes.

Comment: I'm thinking it's best practice to make that clear in all derived classes by declaring all inherited virtual functions virtual?

Comment: @briansrls better practice is declaring overriding functions `override` (which then makes `virtual` rather redundant).

Comment: In other words it’s “virtual all the way down” :-)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to have a pure virtual function to get polymorphic behavior. Normal virtual function can also accomplish it.

Yes, specifying a function as `virtual` in a class means that it remains `virtual` in all the classes derived from it.

From C++11 onwards, there is also the [`override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) specifier:
 In a member function declaration or definition, `override` ensures that the function is `virtual` and is overriding a virtual function from a base class.

Comment: Okay, I will include override in derived class overridden virtual functions.  Would including the keyword "virtual" and "override" be redundant?

Comment: Yes. See this question and answers for some more info. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466863/isnt-virtual-keyword-redundant-when-override-or-final-specifiers-are-used